# Is it possible to place small images below individual letters with non-canvas HTML?

Tags: html, image

For example I have some markup like this:

`<div>testword</div>`

I want to place a small image below the letter `s` and a different small image below the letter `d`. The image should be centered under the letter so that it's clear what letter it's assigned to. It's also okay to use additional HTML, for example maybe I need to wrap each letter in a `<span>` tag or something.

Is it possible to do this for all browsers without resorting to canvas?

Comment: If you wrap each letter, the rest should be easy; `padding-bottom` with `background-image` should do.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested at comments you can do this by using `background-image` and `padding-bottom`. I've done small [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9REAf/1/) with example to give you some point to start.

```
<div>te<span class='bottom-img'>s</span>twor<span class='bottom-img'>d</span></div>

span.bottom-img
{
    background:url("/img/keys.png") no-repeat 0 10px transparent;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

However you will need to prepare your images to use them with your size of letters